# Table is too long for normal presentation, how do I break it by rows

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am a student, and my data science teacher is requiring us to use a table in our presentation on marathon times across the country. Because of this I have a table that contains the marathon name in one column, and the average time that the marathon took to complete.  However there are 276 different marathons in this table, so the table is 276 rows long.  Is there a way to break the table every 50 rows and resume it on another pair of columns to create a table that displays all the information in  one glance rather then needing to scroll through 276 rows of data.

[This is the table I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tliTz.png)

[And this is the table I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq6Kg.jpg)

I tried using the split function, but that seems to only split the data in the cells of the table and not the rows of the data.

Comment: To clarify before anyone asks, I manually made the result table by taking screenshots of the data and then piecing 4 or 5 images of the table together side by side to make the table.  I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in tablaeu itself.

Comment: I applaud your tenacity and normally I would not suggest this, but since this is a project I will ask; does this need to be a table? Tableau is capable of making a lot of unique visualizations that your data will play nice with.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in Tableau, and it doesn’t even take a lot of work — but you do need to understand table calculations to do it, which takes a bit of time to grasp. I’d start with reading about table calcs in the on-line help, blogs etc. Learn about the INDEX() function and how specifying the partitioning and addressing of a table calc effects its behavior. Depending on your viz, you may have to learn about the “At the Level” feature on the edit table calc dialog.THen , you can use INDEX(), DIV() and the % operator to create calculated fields to define the row and column for marks

Comment: One of the requirements for the class is that the presentation needs to have a table.  I already have several other significantly better charts that are much better for the dataset I have been given.  Such as scatter plots, Box and Whisker plots, and trend lines

Comment: Here is an example showing how to use INDEX() to wrap a table. https://public.tableau.com/views/TableWrapExample/Dashboard1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example showing how to define row and column calculations using table calcs to make a table of varying size

https://public.tableau.com/views/TableWrapExample/Dashboard1